# How extend class by another class?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have tree classes:

```
class ClassificatorOrganizationsModel {
    protectedcode: string | undefined;
}

class EduUnitModel {
  paren1tId: number | undefined;
  paren2tId: number | undefined;
  paren3tId: number | undefined;
  phone: string | undefined;
}

export class EduOrganizationModel {
  regionId: number | undefined;
  addressId: number | undefined;

}
```

I need that class `EduOrganizationModel` will be extended by `EduUnitModel` and `ClassificatorOrganizationsModel`.

As result I need to get class `EduOrganizationModel` with all properties including children.

So, I can not do this:

```
class EduOrganizationModel extends EduUnitModel, ClassificatorOrganizationsModel {
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: TS does not allow multiple inheritance. Not without some hacks but it's all workarounds that confirm the fact. I would *guess* that you are doing something wrong if you absolutely need multiple inheritance - a lot of languages disallow it because it's a can of worms and a magnet for design problems. I would suggest a re-design to break the multiple inheritance into something that's better supported.

Comment: Problem is that new class `Class A {}` can contain the same field as `EduUnit Model` and some own. That why I try to use multi inheritance to avoid DRY. So, it is only model class without realization.

Comment: If it's just a *field*, then isn't an interface the better option? You can have a class implement as many interfaces as you want.

Comment: If to use interface I can not fill it, I need a ready model to get/set properties outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mixins https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html
for multiple inheritance.

```
interface EduOrganizationModel extends EduUnitModel, ClassificatorOrganizationsModel {}
applyMixins(EduOrganizationModel, [EduUnitModel, ClassificatorOrganizationsModel]);

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name));
        });
    });
}
```